# Need help in SQL query Group function

Tags: mysql, sql

i am using mysql.
I have a table called zim_new_usa
I want a list of all emails which are of type aol and gmail
the table has a column called `office state`

there are 50 states in USA i want 500 emails from each state. I don't know how to write group function in query. 
the query i tried to use is

```
select *  from zim_new_usa where 
(email like '%@aol%' or email like '%@gmail%') and length(`office state`) = 2
```

Comment: do you have index `office state` in your `zim_new_usa` table?

Comment: there is no index on column `office state`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no possibility to debug, 
But try this:

```
SET @num := 0, @state:= '';

SELECT t.email, t.`office state`, 
      @num := if(@state = t.`office state`, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
      @state := t.`office state` AS dummy
FROM (
  SELECT email, `office state` 
  FROM zim_new_usa 
  WHERE 
  (email LIKE '%@aol%' OR email LIKE '%@gmail%') 
 AND length(`office state`) = 2 
 ORDER BY `office state`
) as t
GROUP BY t.`office state`,t.email
HAVING row_number <= 5;
```

By the way, try to avoid using spaces when title table or column.

Comment: Respect it worked, thanks you very much. now i am changing  row_number <= 500. to get the right answer. Honestly you should take my job :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

[Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

You need a Group by clause for the email and for the office_state fields.

Comment: I want 500 emails from each state,  If i do group by email and limit 25000, it does not give me right answer, it is possible the query fetch more than 500 for a state.